# NGINX cannot create it's own .conf file on Windows 10

Tags: nginx, rtmp

When I cd into the nginx folder as an admin in CMD, and run nginx.exe, it fails to create its config file. I have tried a local vs a online account and different versions of nginx.

The error message is:

> nginx: [emerg] CreateFile() "c:\nginx\conf\nginx.conf" failed (2: FormatMessage() error:(15100))

Comment: When you run your console do you use `cmd /D` ?  The `/D` prevents running an AutoRun script that opens a sub-console that can cause problems when writing to directories, as it "thinks" it's in the incorrect directory..

Comment: No I do not use /D and a sub console is running for about a second but after that it just spits out the error